# Trying to print smallest, biggest and the mean value. Smallest isn't being printed correctly

Tags: c, input, printf, scanf

So, I'm trying to create a program that outputs the smallest input, the biggest input, and the mean or average of the inputs. So far, the biggest and the average are working, but unless I enter something below 0, the smallest is always printed out as "0.00", even when the smallest is above 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) {

    float input;
    float mean = 0.00;
    float total = 0.00;
    float numOfInput = 0.00;
    float smallest;
    float largest;

    while (scanf ("%f", &input) != EOF && input >= -100000 && input <= 100000) {
        numOfInput++;
        total += input;
        if (input > largest)
            largest = input;
        else if (smallest > input)
            smallest = input;

    }

    mean = (total / numOfInput);
    printf ("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", smallest, largest, mean);
}
```

Any suggestions? I've been stuck on this for almost an hour now. As I said before, this works fine when I input a value below 0, but not for anything above 0.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hint: after the line `float smallest;`, what do you suppose is the value of the variable `smallest`?

Comment: You probably want `scanf("%f",&input) == 1` instead of `!=EOF` (you can have a conversion or matching failure well before `EOF`.)

Comment: @ruakh well I have a feeling it's 0.00, hah. But that's only because I keep getting that value when I run the program. I'm not sure why its value is initially 0.00. Does it have something to do with the other variables I've initialized?

Comment: @Shimzay, well the value of `smallest` will be garbage, as you have not initialized it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried that (and thank you for the suggestion, I'll change it) but it doesn't fix my problem. Thank you though, I'll definitely implement that change

Comment: @AshishAhuja I had it (as well as my other variables) initialized to 0.00 before, but I figured that might have been what was causing the problem

Comment: For your minimum and maximum `float` values, you can `#include <float.h>` and use the following constants to initialize your values: `float smallest = FLT_MAX;` and `float largest = -smallest;` (in that order).

Comment: Also note `int main (void)` is of type `int` and therefore should return a value (e.g. `return 0;` if nothing else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is flaw because 1) `scanf("%f",&input)!=EOF` is not how you check for valid `input` (as David C. Rankin pointed out); and 2) you did not initialize `smallest` and `largest`; so strictly speaking your result can be undefined.

I think what you need is to initialize your `smallest` and `largest` number to the first valid `input`.

```
float input; 
float mean = 0.00;
float total = 0.00;
unsigned int numOfInput = 0;  // <-- note this is `unsigned int`, not `float`
float smallest = 0; // <-- don't forget this
float largest = 0;  // <-- and this

while( scanf("%f",&input)==1 && input>= -100000 && input <= 100000 )
{
    numOfInput++;
    if( numOfInput == 1 )  // <-- Assign `smallest` and `largest` on first valid input
    {
        smallest = input;
        largest = input;
    }

    total += input; 

    if(input>largest)
        largest = input;
    else if(smallest>input)
        smallest = input;
}
```

Comment: This works successfully! I just have one doubt: How does the program work with `noOfInput` to be a float? Doing `++` would change it to `0.1`, `0.2` etc.

Comment: @AshishAhuja - well spot, it should be `unsigned`. I'm editing it now - thanks

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, that really helped. Although now I have a new problem it seems. When I enter 0 as one of the inputs alongside 3 and 4 (for example), it defaults to 3 as the smallest input. Any ideas for that? Thank you!

Comment: @Shimzay - are you sure?

Comment: @artm yes, now I'm actually having an entirely new problem.. If the smallest input is the FIRST input, then it gets overwritten by the next smallest input. For example, if I enter: 1.2 3.7 and 8.9 (in that order) the smallest input becomes 3.7. But if I enter it like this : 3.7 1.2 8.9, then 1.2 becomes the smallest

Comment: @artm I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @artm yup! The "new" problem is still occurring. If the smallest value is entered FIRST, then it ignores it and just picks the lowest of the subsequent values. However, it still gets included in the average calculation. Just not in the "smallest" assignment

Comment: @artm (sorry to keep spamming you with comments) but in actual fact, this bug persists for BOTH values. I.e., if I enter the largest value first (we'll say 84) and then I enter 3 and 5, 5 is output as the biggest value.

Comment: @artm NEVERMIND! Got it working. I guess I should have just copy and pasted your code.. Sorry about that. I ended up writing the changes in myself, and didn't realize I hadn't shifted the numOfInput to the top of the first if condition. Thank you so much for all your hard work man! I accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `if...else` instead of `if... else if`

```
if(input>largest)
        largest = input;
else 
        smallest = input;
```

Why? because if the `input` is not larger than `largest` value than its obvious that its gonna be smallest and you can directly store the value in `smallest` variable.
Try this and definitely you will get the right answer.